# Electrical wiring broken

Tags: electrical, repair

I wanted to replace our under cabinet Halogen bulbs with LED. So I got the LED lights from Home Depot and when testing them from an electrical outlet, I accidentally had the two wires coming together and there was a spark.

The circuit breaker did not trip but none of the outlets are working. Here is the picture

[image]

That was the wire that I connected to the electrical outlet and the two wires got connected accidentally and got short-circuited.

As a result, the outlet is not working - there is no power coming through the outlet and the other outlets in that circuit are not working as well

Do you think I should replace the outlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a ground fault outlet that has tripped. look around your kitchen for an outlet with a red and a black button on it and reset it. You might have to look in your breaker panel for a breaker with a reset button on it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I had to rest the breaker and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to throw parts and effort at the problem, you could try replacing the outlet.  But most circuits are wired as strings from the panel - hot and neutral are carried to the first outlet, then to the second, then to the third, etc.

Any problem must be either at the first place that has failed, or the last place that is still good.  Outlets using "backstabs" are a common culprit, since backstabs cannot handle surge current and quickly burn out.